# Problem btw Azure Devops and Azure Blob Storage (Copt and delete)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, credentials

I have a blob site where Jekyll content is reposited to Azure Devops, built there and then copied to Azure Blob Storage (after deletion there). This has worked for some time but I haven't submitted for a number of months. The site builds OK on Devops but the Releases part of the pipeline now fails:

```
2023-02-10T09:09:47.1389516Z ##[error]Error Code: [1]
2023-02-10T09:09:47.1406406Z ##[error]Error: Azure login failed
2023-02-10T09:09:47.1410661Z ##[error]Script failed with error: ERROR: AADSTS7000222: 
The provided client secret keys for app '***' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app: https://aka.ms/NewClientSecret, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: https://aka.ms/certCreds.
```

I did regenerate the Storage Account Access Keys and included the change in the Pipeline settings. But as per my earlier blog post on this same issue, that is a "furphy". Its the Service Connection that has to be updated. As per previous resolution, I followed the steps in my blog down to (Under Resolution) step 11. where the Azure Subscription is selectable. When an attempt is made to select the Resource Group (step 12.) it times out. That's my issue.

- Link to the blog post: https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au/web/Azure_Devops-Blob_Storage_Credentials-mm-web.html
- The Azure Account owner is different to the Devops owner but in the past that has been OK because I can login to Devops with the Azure Account credentials.
- I have updated the script to use latest OS. Was 2019 which was limiting what could be done.

  - Nb: The Build step in the pipeline was separately restored to Windows 2019 as one step in it failed."Install Jekyll and bundler":

    gem install jekyll bundler

So at the moment I can't add content to my blog site. Help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Next day on another system I was able to get through steps 10 onwards as at step 10 an az login popped up.  This then populated the Azure Subscription and was able to select the Azure Group.  Everything else followed OK, I did have to edit the Release scripts a couple of times before the changes filtered through.
All good now. I can now submit new blog content. :)